# Struts 1 Validation - XML defined Constants in \xNN Format leading to false errors on bea weblogic 11g

Tags: struts, xml-validation, struts-1, weblogic11g

Im defining validation constants in "Struts 1" validation using a notation like:

```
<constant-name>chars</constant-name>
<constant-value>[\x20\x21\x5C\x22]</constant-value>
```

This seemed to work for a long time on Oracle IAS 10g,
but now after migration to Bea Weblogic 11g the validation against this MASK
returns false errors.

```
<var-name>mask</var-name>
<var-value>^${chars}*$</var-name>
```

Debugging into the Validation Framework I have found out, that the above constant value
is seemingly taken literally.

The Files are encoded in ANSI as ISO-8859-1 Standard with Unix Format.

Does anyone know what could have gone wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The Cause for my Problem was seemingly that multiple source files were encoded in UTF-8 while the Server environment was expecting ansi encoding.